# filter tree view of header model on base of values of the detail model

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have a model 'purchase_approval_item' with an invoice_id

multiple people approve the invoice and they are registered in the model 'purchase_approval_item_line'

Now i need to show the 'purchase_approval_item' in a tree view, but filter is for the logged in user.

I want to add one2many field in 'purchase_approval_item', approved_by_ids which should be the uids of the approvers. And i want to use that one2many field to filter the treeview.

How can i do this with the openerp framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter the `purchase_approval_item` tree to have only the records where the `approved_by_ids` one2many field contains a certain a user - probably the current one.

You should have a search view for your `purchase_approval_item` model, with:

```
<filter domain="[('approved_by_ids', 'in', [uid])]" 
        name="filter_my_approvals" string="My Approvals" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a **record rule**. which will let user to see only record approved by him/her in tree view.

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="resource_approved_record">
    <field name="name">See Own Approved record</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_purchase_approval_item"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('approved_by_ids', 'in', [user.id]])]</field>
</record>
```